# How do i set the configs for firebase in a flask app?

Tags: firebase, flask, heroku, config

I have deployed my app to heroku and set the configs on the dashboard but my app keeps crashing. I think I'm conceptually not understanding and am unable to fix it. I really am not clear if the PRIVATE_KEY value should just be the string or include the line breaks?
This is my firebase_config.py.

```
`import os
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, storage, initialize_app
import google.cloud.firestore as firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate({
    "type": os.environ.get("TYPE"),
    "project_id": os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID"),
    "private_key_id": os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
    "private_key": os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY").replace('\\n', '\n'),
    "client_email": os.environ.get("CLIENT_EMAIL"),
    "client_id": os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID"),
    "auth_uri": os.environ.get("AUTH_URI"),
    "token_uri": os.environ.get("TOKEN_URI"),
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
    "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL")
})

default_app = initialize_app(cred)

# Firestore client
db = firestore.Client()

bucket = storage.bucket(app=default_app)`
```

When i run the logs . . . I think this is the main problem but i could be wrong

error raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)
2023-06-21T15:01:05.100465+00:00 app[web.1]: google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.